# Окончание фамилий

Tags: орфография, ономастика

Как правильно писать окончания фамилий: "-цын" или "-цин"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В прилагательных после Ц всегда пишется Ы: *синицын, сестрицын*. Однако в фамилиях допустимо и "-цын", и "-цин". Все зависит от самой фамилии и того, как она зарегистрирована.

Answer (score 0):

В суффиксе притяжательных прилагательных в суффиксе -ын- пишется ы: лисицын хвост, птицын клюв.
И только Ельцин.

Comment: Не только Ельцын. Фамилии могут писаться по-разному.